# Logical Subsetting in Mata

Tags: r, subset, stata

In Mata (the matrix language in Stata), I am trying to find logical subsetting or that's equivalent.

Consider that we have a matrix:

```
clear all

version 18
mata: tmp = (-0.5, 1 \ 5, -5)
```

Here, I want to replace positive and negative numbers with 1 and -1, respectively. (That is, in my problem, only signs matter)

So, the result I want is

```
       1    2
    +-----------+
  1 |  -1       |
  2 |   1   -1  |
    +-----------+
```

If I am using R, I may use logical subsetting like below:

```
tmp <- matrix(c(-0.5, 1, 5, -5), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)

> tmp
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] -0.5    1
[2,]  1.0   -5

tmp[tmp > 0] <- 1
tmp[tmp < 0] <- -1

> tmp
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    1
[2,]    1   -1
```

But I cannot find how to do the same thing in Mata.

Comment: Never MATA, always Mata in writing or `mata` in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a case for the `sign()` function.

```
. mata
------------------------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) --------------------------------------------------------------
: tmp = (-0.5, 1 \ 5, -5)

: sign(tmp)
[symmetric]
        1    2
    +-----------+
  1 |  -1       |
  2 |   1   -1  |
    +-----------+
```

I am not an R expert but I'm confident at guessing that R has such a function too, so there's an equally direct solution.

Comment: I looked it up. `sign()` in R is documented as a working for a vector. Whether it works for a matrix too or how to apply it to a matrix is a question for R people.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that kind of function. It is exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: `sign` is vectorized and works fine for matrices, e.,g. `matrix(-2:2, 3, 5) |> sign()`.

Comment: @jay.sf That's good to hear, and matches the guess in my answer, but I didn't infer it from the documentation.